# Angular GetCookie Method from SO does not work anymore

Tags: angular, typescript, cookies

I have the following code from SO:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class CookieService {


  constructor() { }

  public getCookie(name: string) {
    const ca: Array<string> = document.cookie.split(';');
    const caLen: number = ca.length;
    const cookieName = `${name}=`;
    let c: string;

    for (let i = 0; i < caLen; i += 1) {
      c = ca[i].replace(/^\s+/g, '');
      if (c.indexOf(cookieName) === 0) {
        return c.substring(cookieName.length, c.length);
      }
    }
    return '';
  }

  public deleteCookie(name: string) {
    this.setCookie(name, '', -1);
  }
  /**
   * Expires default 1 day
   * If params.session is set and true expires is not added
   * If params.path is not set or value is not greater than 0 its default value will be root "/"
   * Secure flag can be activated only with https implemented
   * Examples of usage:
   * {service instance}.setCookie({name:'token',value:'abcd12345', session:true }); <- This cookie will not expire
   * {service instance}.setCookie({name:'userName',value:'John Doe', secure:true }); <- If page is not https then secure will not apply
   * {service instance}.setCookie({name:'niceCar', value:'red', expireDays:10 }); <- For all this examples if path is not provided default will be root
   */

  public setCookie(name: string, value: string, expireDays: number, path: string = '') {
    const d: Date = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + expireDays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
    const expires: string = 'expires=' + d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = name + '=' + value + '; ' + expires + (path.length > 0 ? '; path=' + path : '');
  }
}
```

When I try to `console.log(this.CookieService.getCookie('cookienamehere');` the cookie does not get displayed and an empty string gets printed out instead... What happened? It used to work... The code has been mildly corrected to contain const and etc as you can see in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic you got from SO should work. I had a similiar issue, because the browser did not share cookies to the client if it's not `https`.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are only reading the cookie not writing it.

Why you don't get cookie data might be due to cookie access is restricted.

Options are:

- HTTP-only, and thus not readable from JS (if browser support HTTP-only cookies, most do).
- Secure, only by https resources.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies#Restrict_access_to_cookies

For next steps try to access cookie directly ( `console.log(document.cookie)` ), and check for your cookie there, if it's not available then you either don't have the cookie or you are dealing with restricted cookie access.

Comment: I am trying to read the cookie first, writing comes later.